# input-group height when (span - input - button)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to build a 3 control input-group with Bootstrap 3.3.7, however the height of the first addon does not match the following input nor button.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Amount</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have a working sample to solve this design?

Comment: I've observed similar behavior, but this code by itself in Bootstrap 3.3.7 does not seem to be affected: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/23819/

Answer (score 0):

First and for all where is your `<label>` tag?

Do you want the submit in your input field? Or the submit button underneath it?

You need also to place form around it and your input can be declared as number because it's amount; your input field also needs a name. A submit button is an input button with type='submit':
example:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit" id="submit">
```

You can also declare on your body class='container'

```
<body class="container">
    <form id="youWantToGiveThisAName" class="form-group">
    <label for="amountOfSomething"></label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Amount</span>
        <input type="number" name="amountOfSomething" id="amountOfSomething" class="form-control" value="0.00000121">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-coinchecker pull-right" value="submit" id="submit">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmc6k39v/) to see the result

Comment: The desired design is an inline input-group with 
    | text | input | button |

For the construct of the issue, form and/or label tags are irrelevant.

Comment: It seems to work using Bootstrap 4 with the original code from the post. But bootstrap 3.3.7 does not comply. Anyone ?